# Error: Failed to initialize react-native-reanimated library

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

Trying to create a drawer navigator in React Native using VSCode.

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
```

When I get this error:

> Error: Failed to initialize react-native-reanimated library, make sure you followed installation steps here: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/
>
> 1. Make sure reanimated's babel plugin is installed in your babel.config.js (you should have 'react-native-reanimated/plugin' listed there - also see the above link for details)
> 2. Make sure you reset build cache after updating the config, run: yarn start --reset-cache, js engine: hermes

I made sure that everything in babel.config.js is correct:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```

I added the following import to **the top** my root file (App.js):

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

I reset my cache too using:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Here are also all of my packages:

```
...
...
...

"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.6",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2"
  },

...
...
...
```

Comment: Did you clear your Metro cache and rebuild?

Comment: Yes. I have done that

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue, was fixed by running
`npm start -- --reset-cache`

Comment: I tried that... it didn't help unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Try installing preset by

```
npm i metro-react-native-babel-preset --save-dev
```

and then

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```